# UITableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath Cell returns on unselected Not on Selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My table view returns the row on unSelect instead of onSelect, so when I select the first cell didDeselectRowAtIndexPath return nothing, but when I select other cell I get the unselecting cell row instead of the one select. Working backwards?

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);
    _myLabel.text = [myDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` did you even read the method name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You are using `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. If you want to select a particular row on tap, you will need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method instead of didDeselectRowAtIndexPath.